Got stuck on trying to progress my code using while loops
After a total revamp of my code since my last post I've made this so far but I need progressing from here and I feel stuck. The last mistake I made was having too many if else statements and I don't want to repeat that here. I want to create different inventories for each of the traders and have it be possible for the user to select between which trader he wants to buy / sell from and then when he's done be able to either quit the game, select a different trader or switch worlds. Then in different worlds I also want to have different traders and what not, I want it to be randomized.
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class World {
    // A class to create the worlds

private:

    string world_name;
    string world_description;

public:

    void create_world(string name, string w_description) {
        // Creates different worlds
        world_name = name;
        world_description = w_description;
    }
    string greet() const {
        // A greeting function
        return "Welcome to the world of " + world_name + "!\n" + world_description + '\n';
    }

    string get_world_name() const {
        return world_name;
    }

    string get_world_description() const {
        return world_description;
    }
};

class Inventory {
    // A class to initialize the inventory

private:

    map<string, int> inventory;

public:

    void create_inventory(string item_name, int item_price) {
        // Creates the inventory
        inventory[item_name] = item_price;
    }

    void show_inventory(string currency_name) {
        cout << "Inventory: \n";
        for (const auto& item : inventory) {
            cout << item.first << " - " << item.second << ' ' << currency_name << '\n';
        }
    }
};

class Trader {
    // A class to initialize the traders

private:

    string trader_name;

public:

    void create_traders(string name) {
        // Creates the traders
        trader_name = name;
    }

    string get_trader_names() const {
        return trader_name;
    }
};

int main() {

    // World initializing and creating
    vector<World> worlds;

    World w1, w2, w3;
    w1.create_world("Celestia Falls","A world hidden in the waterfalls of Gonkun.");
    w2.create_world("Skypedia", "A world hidden in the clouds of Gonkun.");
    w3.create_world("Wano", "A world hidden somewhere in the oceans of Gonkun.");

    // Adds the worlds to the vector
    worlds.push_back(w1);
    worlds.push_back(w2);
    worlds.push_back(w3);

    cout << "Welcome to the world of Gonkun where you can find anything you'd want in the many islands here.\n";
    cout << "Select the number of the world you'd first like to go to.\n";
    cout << "Press return after selecting an option.\n\n";

    // Displays the world options
    for (size_t i = 0; i < worlds.size(); ++i) {
        cout << i + 1 << ". " << worlds[i].get_world_name() << '\n';
    }

    bool run = true;
    while (run) {
        int world_choice;
        cin >> world_choice;

        // Validate the input and display the chosen world
        if (world_choice >= 1 && world_choice <= worlds.size()) {
            cout << '\n' << worlds[world_choice - 1].greet() << "\n";
            run = false;
        }
        else {
            cout << "Please select a valid choice.\n";
        }
    }
    
    vector<Trader> traders;

    vector<string> trader_names = {
        "Zephyr", "Cyrus", "Luna", "Eos"
    };

    for (size_t i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
        Trader trader;
        trader.create_traders(trader_names[i]);
        traders.push_back(trader);
    }

    for (size_t i = 0; i < traders.size(); ++i) {
        cout << i + 1 << ". " << traders[i].get_trader_names() << '\n';
    }

    cout << "Pick the number of the trader you'd like to trade with.\n\n";

    return 0;
}

I've tried if else statements but they get too long and I wanna optimize my code. I've also tried while loops but I got lost in them and I don't exactly know how I could structure it in a way that works properly.

I don't understand what your problem is: You "have tried [to do stuff]" but you do not explain what for nor why it failed and the only thing I see as incorrect at first glance is exiting your program right after doing cout << "Pick the number of the trader you'd like to trade with.\n\n"; but that does not look like it is what you are asking. Apart from that, your code needs cleaning. I do not see any place where the Inventory class is used...

What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems

My suggestion would be to read the inventories and traders from a file. You could have say 20 traders and their inventories in a file and randomly assign them to different worlds. Also if you want traders to be associated with a world then a vector of traders should be part of the world class, not separate. And in the same way, if you want an inventory to be associated with a trader then an inventory should be part of the trader class. Design is one of the hardest things for newbies, think about your classes and the relationships between them. It seems you haven't done the last part.

For starters:
It seems you do not have a clear design/layout for how you want your programs workflow to execute. I suggest you spend some time on paper jotting down your ideas and how you want the over all flow to work. I have done a bit of updating for you in terms of how I would imagine the game to run. You'll see a bit of more modernized concepts here as well.
I think you need to understand the concept of while loops inside of while loops and how to successfully break out of them at the proper time.
Nevertheless, here is some updating code to get you started.
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <thread>

// Constant for exit code from working while loop
constexpr int EXIT_CODE = -1;

/// @brief Forces a user to input a valid numeric input
/// @param min - minimum acceptable input value
/// @param max - maximum acceptable input value
/// @return - validated user input
static int GetValidInput(int min, int max, int breakout)
{
    int userInput;
    bool valid = false;

    while (!valid)
    {
        std::cin.clear();
        std::cout << "Please enter a valid numeric value (" << breakout << " to exit): ";
        std::cin >> userInput;

        // Check if the input failed (not a number)
        if (std::cin.fail())
        {
            // Clear error flags and ignore invalid input
            std::cin.clear();
            std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
            std::cout << "That's not a valid number. Please try again." << std::endl;
        }
        else if (userInput == breakout)
        {
            return breakout;
        }
        else if (userInput < min || userInput > max)
        {
            // Check if the number is within the valid range
            std::cout << "The number is out of range. Please enter a number between 0 and 3." << std::endl;
        }
        else {
            // Input is valid and within the range
            valid = true;
        }
    }

    std::cin.clear();
    return userInput;
}


/// @brief A class to represent an item
class Item
{
public:
    Item() {}
    Item(std::string name, std::string description, unsigned int quantity, double price) : Item()
    {
        m_name = name;
        m_description = description;
        m_quantity = quantity;
        m_price = price;
    }

    std::string GetName() const
    {
        return m_name;
    }

    std::string GetDescription() const
    {
        return m_description;
    }

    unsigned int GetQuantity() const
    {
        return m_quantity;
    }

    double GetPrice() const
    {
        return m_price;
    }

    bool SetPrice(const double price)
    {
        m_price = price;
        return m_price == price;
    }

    unsigned int IncrementQuantity(const unsigned int increment)
    {
        return (m_quantity += increment);
    }

    unsigned int DecrementQuantity(const unsigned int deccrement)
    {
        m_quantity = (m_quantity - deccrement) <= 0 ? 0 : m_quantity -= deccrement;
        return m_quantity;
    }

private:
    unsigned int m_quantity = 0;
    std::string m_name;
    std::string m_description;
    double m_price = 0;
};

/// @brief A class to initialize the traders
class Trader {
private:
    std::string m_name;
    std::string m_bio;
    std::vector<Item> m_inventory;

public:
    Trader(std::string name, std::string bio)
    {
        m_name = name;
        m_bio = bio;
    }

    std::string GetName() const 
    {
        return m_name;
    }

    std::string GetBio() const 
    {
        return m_bio;
    }

    void AddInventory(Item item)
    {
        m_inventory.push_back(item);
    }
};

/// @brief A class to create the worlds
class World 
{
private:

    std::string m_worldName;
    std::string m_worldDescription;
    std::vector<Trader> m_traders;

public:
    World() = default;

    World(std::string name, std::string w_description)
        : m_worldName(std::move(name)), m_worldDescription(std::move(w_description)) {}

    // Default Destructor
    ~World() = default;

    // Default Copy Constructor
    World(const World&) = default;

    // Default Copy Assignment Operator
    World& operator=(const World&) = default;

    // Default Move Constructor
    World(World&&) noexcept = default;

    // Default Move Assignment Operator
    World& operator=(World&&) noexcept = default;

    void CreateWorld(std::string name, std::string w_description) {
        // Creates different worlds
        m_worldName = name;
        m_worldDescription = w_description;
    }
    std::string Greet() const {
        // A greeting function
        return "\nWelcome to the world of " + m_worldName + "!\n" + m_worldDescription + '\n';
    }

    std::string GetWorldName() const {
        return m_worldName;
    }

    std::string GetWorldDescription() const {
        return m_worldDescription;
    }

    void AddTrader(Trader newTrader)
    {
        m_traders.push_back(newTrader);
    }

    void PrintTraders()
    {
        if (m_traders.size() == 0)
        {
            std::cout << "No Active Traders In This World!\nReturning to transport hub!\n\n";
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << "\nTraders:\n";
            for (size_t i = 0; i < m_traders.size(); ++i)
            {
                Trader temp = m_traders[i];
                std::cout << "\t" << i << ": " << temp.GetName() << " - " << temp.GetBio() << "\n";
            }
        }

        std::cout << std::endl;
    }

    void WorldInterface()
    {
        bool run = true;
        std::cout << Greet();
        PrintTraders();

        if (m_traders.size() <= 0)
        {
            std::cout << "No traders on this world!\n";
            run = false;
        }

        while (run)
        {
            // Allow the user to interact with the world; 

            int input = GetValidInput(1, m_traders.size(), EXIT_CODE);

            switch (input)
            {
            case EXIT_CODE:
                run = false;
                continue;
            case 1:
                break;
            case 2:
                break;
            case 3:
                break;
            default:
                break;
            }
        }

        std::cout << "Returning to transport hub!\n";
    }
};

class GameMap
{
public:
    GameMap()
    {
        // Adds the worlds to the vector
        m_worlds.push_back(World("Celestia Falls", "A world hidden in the waterfalls of Gonkun."));
        m_worlds.push_back(World("Skypedia", "A world hidden in the clouds of Gonkun."));
        m_worlds.push_back(World("Wano", "A world hidden somewhere in the oceans of Gonkun."));

        m_worlds[0].AddTrader(Trader("Chip", "A helpful trader specializing in software."));
        m_worlds[0].AddTrader(Trader("Cyborg", "A unique trader specializing in rare electronics."));
    }

    void PrintWelcome()
    {
        std::cout << "Welcome to the world of Gonkun where you can find anything you'd want in the many islands here.\n"
        << "Select the number of the world you'd like to visit.\n"
        << "Press return after selecting an option.\n\n";
    }

    void PrintWorlds()
    {
        std::cout << "\nWorlds:\n";
        for (size_t i = 0; i < m_worlds.size(); ++i) 
        {
            World temp = m_worlds[i];
            std::cout << "\t" << i + 1 << ": " << temp.GetWorldName() << " - " << temp.GetWorldDescription() << "\n";
        }

        std::cout << std::endl;
    }

    int GetNumberOfWorlds()
    {
        return m_worlds.size();
    }

    bool ChangeWorld(unsigned int worldNumber)
    {
        try {
            m_activeWorld = &m_worlds.at(worldNumber);
            return true;
        }
        catch (const std::out_of_range& e) {
            // Handle the case where the index is out of range
            std::cerr << "Caught an out_of_range exception: " << e.what() << std::endl;
        }
        catch (const std::exception& e) {
            // Handle other potential exceptions
            std::cerr << "Caught an exception: " << e.what() << std::endl;
        }

        return false;
    }

    World* GetActiveWorld()
    {
        return m_activeWorld;
    }

private:
    std::vector<World> m_worlds;
    World* m_activeWorld = nullptr;
};

int main() 
{
    GameMap map;
    map.PrintWelcome();

    bool run = true;
    while (run) 
    {
        map.PrintWorlds();
        int input = GetValidInput(1, map.GetNumberOfWorlds(), EXIT_CODE);
        bool goodTransport = false;

        switch (input)
        {
        case EXIT_CODE:
            run = false;
            continue; // continue to next iteration of loop. Will exit.
        case 1:
            [[fallthrough]];
        case 2:
            [[fallthrough]];
        case 3:
            goodTransport = map.ChangeWorld(input-1);
            break;
        case 0:
        default:
            break;
        }

        if (not goodTransport)
        {
            std::cout << "[ERROR] - Failed to transport to new world!\n";
            continue;
        }
        else
        {
            std::string message = "Transporting.....";
            std::cout << message;
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(500));
            std::cout << "\r" << std::string(message.size(), ' ') << "\r";
        }

        World* currentWorld = map.GetActiveWorld();

        if (currentWorld != nullptr)
        {
            currentWorld->WorldInterface();
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << "[ERROR] - Got lost transporting to new world!";
        }

        std::cout << "\n\n\n";
    }

    std::cout << "Closing!";
    return 0;
}

